# Creating a groupBy function with varargs in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a following function to groupBy single or multiple columns in scala.

```
def showGroupByDesc(df: DataFrame, cols: Column*): Unit = {
    df.groupBy(cols).count().sort($"count".desc).show()
  }
```

But this code errors out by saying:

```
overloaded method value groupBy with alternatives:
  (col1: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset <and>
  (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset
 cannot be applied to (Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column])
```

From the error, it seems that scala is compiling to the following method:

```
@scala.annotation.varargs
  def groupBy(col1: String, cols: String*): RelationalGroupedDataset = {
    val colNames: Seq[String] = col1 +: cols
    RelationalGroupedDataset(
      toDF(), colNames.map(colName => resolve(colName)), RelationalGroupedDataset.GroupByType)
  }
```

whereas I actually want to use the following overridden method:

```
@scala.annotation.varargs
  def groupBy(cols: Column*): RelationalGroupedDataset = {
    RelationalGroupedDataset(toDF(), cols.map(_.expr), RelationalGroupedDataset.GroupByType)
  }
```

Shouldn't it automatically pick the right function through method overriding? Might be a dumb question, any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `:_*` to passed `cols` into `groupBy`:

```
def showGroupByDesc(df: DataFrame, cols: Column*): Unit = {
  df.groupBy(cols:_*).count().sort($"count".desc).show()
}
```

it's a special syntax for passing arguments to `varargs` functions in scala.

Without `:_*` compiler is looking for function which accepts `Seq[Column]` and will not found it.

You can read more about functions with varargs [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-define-methods-variable-arguments-varargs-fields/) for example.